# Conditional quit multiprocess in python

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm trying to build a python script that runs several processes in parallel. Basically, the processes are independent, work on different folders and leave their output as text files in those folders. But in some special cases, a process might terminate with a special (boolean) status. If so, I want all the other processes to terminate right away. What is the best way to do this?

I've fiddled with multiprocessing.condition() and multiprocessing.manager, after reading the excellent tutorial by Doug Hellmann:
http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html
However, I do not seem to understand how to get a multiprocessing process to monitor a status indicator and quit if it takes a special value.

To examplify this, I've written the small script below. It somewhat does what I want, but ends in an exception. Suggestions on more elegant ways to proceed are gratefully welcomed:

br,
Gro

```
import multiprocessing

def input(i):
    """arbitrary chosen value(8) gives special status = 1"""        
    if i == 8:
        value = 1
    else:
        value = 0
    return value

def sum_list(list):
"""accumulative sum of list"""
    sum = 0
    for x in range(len(list)):
            sum = sum + list[x]
    return sum

def worker(list,i):
    value = input(i)
    list[i] = value
    print 'processname',i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    list = mgr.list([0]*20)
    jobs = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(list,i))
                for i in range(20)
        ]
for j in jobs:
    j.start()
    sumlist = sum_list(list)
    print sumlist
    if sumlist == 1:
        break
for j in jobs:
    j.join()
```